# Postfix configure <the database with non-UNIX accounts> in local_recipient_maps

Tags: postfix

What form would the configuration of `<the database with non-UNIX accounts>` take?

```
# in /etc/postfix/main.cf
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname, $alias_maps,
    <the database with non-UNIX accounts>
```

The documentation page http://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html seems incomplete in that sense.

An example would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

It is not incomplete. You just miss this important line

> See the section "Local recipient table format" below for a description of how the table should be populated.

that point to [this section](http://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html#format).

> If you use local files in postmap(1) format, then local_recipient_maps expects the following table format:
>
> - In the left-hand side, specify a bare username, an "@domain.tld" wild-card, or specify a complete "user@domain.tld" address.
> - You have to specify something on the right-hand side of the table, but the value is ignored by local_recipient_maps.

So the example would be

```
nonexistaa   dummyaccount
nonexistbb@example.com   dummyaccount
```